# Append draggable and dynamic label jquery

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to generate dynamic labels and add each one of them to cells of a table when I click a button. This is my code:

```
var i=0;
$("#next").on("click",function ()
{
   $(".item").each(function(e) //scorre ogni cella della tabella con classe 
   {    
       $(this).html("<label id=txt"+i+" class=tagElem draggable=true>Hello</label>");
       i++;
   });      
 });
```

When I try to drag one of this label into a droppable div, a get this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'
```

I have read a lot of topic about it, but no one of them was my case.
Could someone explain me because it happens?

Comment: Can you please share some fiddle? It will make easier to help you out.

Comment: Hi Dario thank you. This is just an example:[link](https://jsfiddle.net/d83enL6q/1/) I don't know how to drag the second <li> when I append it to the list1. When I drag into the second list I get the error.

Comment: @Dario This is an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked your code and fixed it in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6y8etu4/4/).
Your problems is in the `dragstart` selector which is not firing for newly added `li` elements but only for the ones which are present when the page is initally loaded.
My fix consists in listening to `dragstart` event on the `document` and then filtering the `li` elements in its callback.